# Generalization of Dirac matrices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Is it possible to have a set of 16-dimensional matrices $\gamma_{\mu}^{a}$ such that
$$\{\gamma_{\mu}^{a},\gamma_{\nu}^{b}\} = 2\delta^{ab}\eta_{\mu\nu}$$
where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and $a$ and $b$ can be 1 or 2? I've been trying to construct them manually but it's tougher than I thought and I can't find any mention of this in the literature.

Edit: And also, such that $\gamma^a_{\mu}\gamma^b_{\nu}$ is not 0.

Comment: ? It is not evident by inspection? a 16x16 matrix with the $\gamma_\mu^1$s in the upper left 4x4 block and zero in the lower right block, and $\gamma_\mu^2$s in the lower right and zero in the upper left does not qualify?  $\gamma_\mu\oplus 0$ and $0\oplus \gamma_\mu$. Isn't this your algebra?

Comment: In that case I will also have $\gamma^{a}_{\mu}\gamma^{b}_{\nu}=0$, which I do not wish. I should've added that, thanks.

Comment: isnt this just $C\ell(2)\otimes C\ell(1,d-1)$? if so, you know the irreps, so take as many direct sums as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AccidentalFourierTransform. I understand what you said and it makes sense, but I don't have enough practice in group theory to actually do what you suggested. Could you quickly sketch how one would do that? Thanks!

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform . Alas, the $\sigma_1$  and $\sigma_2$ in different parts of the anticommutator flip the sign of the conventional Cl. If only one considered a commutator, instead...